# Save UAC prompt credentials

Tags: uac

I have an application that prompts for Admin rights when the current user is not an Admin. I want to be able to save the Admin credentials after the prompt so that the application will not ask for Admin password everytime it is run. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Cannot be done, as this would eliminate the need for UAC. You can turn it off, but that isn't what you're asking

You may be able to get away with using the `runas` command, depending on the program, but doubtful.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't save the password on the UAC.

You can try [CPAU](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/cpau/).

> Command line tool for starting process in alternate security context. Basically this is a runas replacement. Also allows you to create job files and encode the id, password, and command line in a file so it can be used by normal users.

CPAU let's you save the user/password and then use it later. Examples:

> cpau -u joehome\joe -p logon -ex "perl cleanup.pl" -enc -file cleanup.job
>   Creates job file called cleanup.job to run perl script cleanup.pl as joehomejoe
>
> cpau -dec -file cleanup.job -lwp
>   Execute job file cleanup.job

Hope it helps.